# How to Resolve a Question with Very Good, but Wrong Answers?

Tags: discussion

This has almost certainly been asked elsewhere.

I had recently posted a question about firing a sci-fi laser rifle with specs on what I thought a good stereotypical weapon would be. See people answered the question as asked, while others inferred  the spirit of the question correctly, and provided excellent answers not meeting the specification.

I'd like to select an answer and close the question, but I'm not sure how best to. I could :

- Select one of the answers that answers the question as written,
- Modify the text of the question to make it more open to the other answers, and choose one from the broader lot,
- Something else

What's the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author of the question has control of the accepted answer, always. Other users control the up/down votes. Reward the person who gave you the help you were seeking... they should gain achievements from being insightful into your needs. We want to reward such folks.

**I wouldn’t change the question at this time.** But you could add  an endnote to the question saying what you intended to ask to explain why you picked the answer you picked, so anyone who comes looking for the question as asked knows to read other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**There are other possibilities.**

You are not required to "select" an answer at all. Especially if all the answers are wrong!

Sometimes the querent doesn't actually get an answer to his query so much as *insight into the problem* that prompted the query in the first place. For the geopoet, this is every bit as good as a straight up correct answer.

In this case, and without having seen the query or the responses, I'd say the best approach may very be to just let it lie. Selecting and closing a question does impose a subtle psychological negative pressure on many people: when they see the green check mark, they assume that that answer is the end all and be all of all answers. If it's correct and meets your specs, all well and good! But it puts off potential readers from offering a new take, and maybe an even better answer!

Leaving a question whose answers are only partially satisfactory will tend to invite new eyes and fresh perspectives. This is one reason why SE allows you (and any user) to place a bounty on a query. You could add a note saying that so-and-so's answer was good and helpful (but still incorrect) and you're placing a bounty in the hopes of getting a good, helpful AND correct answer!